# Typescript cannot find module for stripe

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I am trying to import a javascript module in my project.  I am trying two different configurations because the vendor who provides the module (Stripe) has two different module formats.  I am getting errors as shown below:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/js",
    "lib": [ "ES2018", "DOM", "ES5", "ES2015", "ES2016", "ESNext" ],
    "module": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types/", "./node_modules/@stripe/" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

#### Configuration 1:

```
import { loadStripe } from '../node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js';
```

Error message:

> index.d.ts is not a module.

File node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.d.ts looks like this:

```
///<reference path='./stripe-js/index.d.ts' />
///<reference path='./api/index.d.ts' />

declare module '@stripe/stripe-js' {
  const loadStripe: (
    publishableKey: string,
    options?: StripeConstructorOptions | undefined
  ) => Promise<Stripe | null>;
}

interface Window {
  // Stripe.js must be loaded directly from https://js.stripe.com/v3, which
  // places a `Stripe` object on the window
  Stripe?: import('@stripe/stripe-js').StripeConstructor;
}
```

I am most likely missing a configuration option in `tsconfig` that will understand `declare module`.  Other modules in my project that I write use `export class...`.  How do I need to change `tsconfig` to accommodate this syntax?

#### Configuration 2:

```
import { loadStripe } from '../node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/pure';
```

File node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/pure.d.ts looks like this:

```
///<reference path='./types/index.d.ts' />

export const loadStripe: typeof import('@stripe/stripe-js').loadStripe & {
  setLoadParameters: (params: {advancedFraudSignals: boolean}) => void;
};
```

If I import as shown above the project builds but fails with 404 at runtime because it is looking for this file which is missing the .js exenstion:

```
https://localhost:5017/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/pure
```

I believe the problem with Option 2 is related to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577) with TypeScript that is over 2 years old.  I am 53 years old I have no reason to believe this problem will be resolved in my lifetime.  That said, this is an option and if there are any known workarounds I would be happy to try one.

The types [found here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15303) are out of date.  Stripe [claims](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-js) they provide types and I would like to use theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.d.ts` is declaring an ambient external module, a practice which should be avoided wherever possible. Hopefully they will fix their type declarations.

It is impossible to import an ambient external module via a relative path.

That said, however, the form of your own imports is a also a practice which should be avoided wherever possible.

Please ***avoid*** importing your dependencies using relative paths even when, as with most modules, they are not typed as ambient externals.

The solution is simple:

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Your solution results in:  "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@stripe/stripe-js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

Comment: What gives you that error? It's not from TypeScript, I just tested it.

Comment: Good question.  I guess I just assumed it was a TS error.  I am researching it.  BTW adding a preceding '/' does not fix it.

Comment: What kind of app is it? Are you using a module loader/bundler, what's your build process? Anyway, `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@stripe/stripe-js"` is definitely not from TypeScript.

Comment: .net core 3.1.  Using msbuild, .net bundler + minifier.

Comment: You're going to run into trouble using that.

Comment: Do you have a utility you recommend?

Comment: Webpack, JSPM, or RequireJS